# AutoCad Command Rejected "Undo" when using Application.Invoke()

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, autocad

I am using Application.Invoke() to invoke AutoLisp commands in AutoCad synchronously. Most of my commands work fine, but there are several that come up with the error

```
Error: AutoCAD command rejected: "_.UNDO"
```

The commands in particular are AutoCad Electrical commands such as c:ace_insertwire and c:wd_insym2.

Here's my code:

```
Using rb As New ResultBuffer()
        rb.Add(New TypedValue(LispDataType.Text, "c:wd_insym2"))
        rb.Add(New TypedValue(LispDataType.Text, name))
        rb.Add(New TypedValue(LispDataType.ListBegin))
        rb.Add(New TypedValue(LispDataType.Double, coords(0)))
        rb.Add(New TypedValue(LispDataType.Double, coords(1)))
        rb.Add(New TypedValue(LispDataType.ListEnd))
        rb.Add(New TypedValue(LispDataType.Nil))
        rb.Add(New TypedValue(LispDataType.Nil))
        Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.Invoke(rb)
End Using
```

This is the equivalent of

```
(c:wd_insym2 "C:/ace_blocks/HT00_001.dwg" '(150 230) nil nil)
```

which works fine.

When I use the same method for ace_insert_wire it gives me an additional error:

```
Error: AutoCAD command rejected: "_.UNDO" AutoCAD command rejected: "_.REDRAW"
```

Any ideas what could be causing this? I certainly did not call either UNDO or REDRAW!

Comment: can you check if the "name" parameter has spaces that AutoCAD can interpret as U or RE?

Comment: @AugustoGoncalves Here's an example: Invoking: ("c:wd_insym2" "//NAS/Design/ACE_Blocks/HCB11_TOL.dwg" (125 250) nil nil)
Error: AutoCAD command rejected: "_.UNDO"

Comment: And can you add the line of code where you call SendStringToExecute?

Comment: @AugustoGoncalves Sorry if my question was unclear. I am now using Application.Invoke() as shown. I will remove the first line of my question as it is confusing and unnecessary.

Comment: Easy.  Coordinates (x,y) are a list object.  A wire cannot have a single point.  There are two ends two a wire.  You only have one point.

Comment: @jdweng sorry not quite sure what you mean here. c:wdinsym2 is a command for inserting schematic components, not wires. it takes a single list xy coordinate.

Comment: You posting says "ace_insert_wire".   A wire is a schematic component with two ends.  Each end must be an x,y coordinate.  You have only one end point which is causing the error.

Comment: @jdweng am I missing something here? My code clearly refers to c:insym2, which inserts a schematic component. Ace_insert_wire was just another example of a command that doesn’t appear to work when executing synchronously

Comment: First open the text file c:insym2.  It looks like it just a definition file and not a type of command.  Most object in AutoCAD are added using one location point (like adding a resistor or any other object).  The point can be the center or corner of the device.  A wire needs have two end points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because `c:wd_insym2` is calling these commands. It fails because your own command is already active. You need to call this command asynchronously with `SendStringToExecute` or may be `Editor.Command/CommandAsync`. If you need to additional processing after the command has executed, add an handler to the `CommandEnded` event:

```
doc.CommandEnded += doc_CommandEnded;
doc.SendStringToExecute("(c:wd_insym2 "C:/ace_blocks/HT00_001.dwg" '(150 230) nil nil)", false, false, false);

[..]

void doc_CommandEnded(object sender, CommandEventArgs args)
{
    // Do what you need to do

    // Remove the handler
    doc.CommandEnded -= doc_CommandEnded;
}
```

You should also add an handler to the `CommandFailed` event in case of failure of the `c:wd_insym2` command.

Comment: Oh dear, I was hoping that wasnt the case. It seems strange that there is no satisfactory way to execute commands synchronously, surely that would be a common request?

Comment: Reentrancy is a complex topic. Here you have your command, calling an Electrical command, which in turn calls another command. UNDO is a special one which can not be transacted.