# Calling LISP command from AutoCAD .NET Editor.CommandAsync

Tags: .net, vb.net, autocad-plugin, autolisp

I am attempting to call an inbuilt AutoCad Electrical LISP command `"c:wd_insym2"` from .NET.
I have recently installed AutoCad 2016 which now has the Editor.Command and Editor.CommandAsync functions, however all the help/forum posts that I can find refer to using it to call AutoCad commands such as LINE, CIRCLE etc.
I want to call a lisp command, such as:

```
(c:wd_insym2 "HPB11.dwg" (list 0 0) 1.0 nil)
```

which inserts a pushbutton symbol at `0, 0`.

Here's what I've got (I have been using CommandAsync because I have had trouble sending that command synchronously using Application.Invoke before: [AutoCad Command Rejected "Undo" when using Application.Invoke()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32513029/autocad-command-rejected-undo-when-using-application-invoke)

```
<CommandMethod("SendCmdAsync", CommandFlags.Modal)>
Async Sub SendCmdAsync()
    Dim doc As Document = DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument
    Dim ed As Editor = doc.Editor
    Dim cmd As String = "(c:wd_insym2 " & ControlChars.Quote & "HPB11.dwg" & ControlChars.Quote & " (list 0 0) nil nil)"
    ed.WriteMessage(vbNewLine & "Trying to execute: <" & cmd & ">" & vbNewLine)
    Await ed.CommandAsync(cmd)
    ed.WriteMessage(vbNewLine & "Done.")
End Sub
```

When I run it it says 'LISP command not available'.

Is what I'm doing possible, and if so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sort of solved the issue - evidently you can't use Command and CommandAsync to run Lisp commands - they're only for AutoCAD commands.

The best way of doing this is Application.Invoke: https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/net/unable-to-find-an-entry-point-in-dll-acad-exe/m-p/5522036/highlight/true#M43404

Although, with my specific Electrical command (c:wd_insym2), when I try this technique in AutoCAD 2014, it gives me an error 'AutoCAD command rejected UNDO'. However, I have just noticed that in AutoCAD 2016 it works fine - I guess they've changed the API somewhere along the line.